# How to "depolarize" a data set

Tags: pca, data-preprocessing

I have a data set whose columns are points and whose rows are features. 
For some features, high scores are good and low scores are bad, but for other features, low scores are good and high scores are bad.
I came across a method for transforming the data set so that scores above the mean are "good," but I need some help understanding it.

Here is the method, which is somewhat similar to PCA. Let $M = [v_1,...,v_N]$ be the data matrix of $N$ points (column vectors). Consider the covariance matrix $$C = \begin{bmatrix} M \\ -M \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} M^T & -M^T\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} MM^T & -MM^T \\ -MM^T & MM^T \end{bmatrix}.$$  Take the eigenvector $E$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $C$. The final step is to take the half of the features $i$ for which $E_i > 0.$  Any ideas about what is going on here?